# How receptive are we to petty edits?

Tags: discussion, editing

I provided an answer to the following question: [NBA Wingspan-To-Height Ratio](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/nba-wingspan-to-height-ratio)

A few days later, an [edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/revisions/20965/2) was made to the question. The word "wingspan" was replaced with "armspan," and the following edit reason was provided:

> People have arms, not wings.

I found two things wrong with this edit:

- "Wingspan" is widely accepted terminology in the NBA. As noted in my answer, the NBA draft combine uses "wingspan" in their measurements. There was nothing wrong with the terminology as initially used.
- Ignoring any potential sarcasm, I found this edit to not only be petty, but also granular and pedantic. Had my answer been edited, I would have reedited it to reinclude the initial terminology.

I was pleased to see the question get reedited to reinclude the original terminology used by the OP.

How receptive are we to petty edits like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume good faith.

Until proven otherwise, my view is that this was a well-meaning edit intended to improve the question. It so happens that "wingspan" is the normal terminology within basketball, but it's certainly not common in everyday speech - for example, the Wikipedia disambiguation page for [Wingspan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingspan_(disambiguation)) doesn't include the meaning for a person, and neither does (say) [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wingspan).

Comment: This is very fair. My concern was having to reedit my answer only for it to be reedited back using the updated term, which would be unnecessary, in my eyes.

Comment: As always, *communicate*. If you're reverting somebody's edit, add a comment or post something in chat to explain why.

Comment: @user16112 I will just add to Philip Kendall's comment that a good place where to explain the reason for editing is the edit summary - it is shown when [displaying the revision history[(https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/20965/revisions).

Comment: @Martin For historical context, that's where I read the reason for the edits.